# Django ORM based reverse lookup

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two models in Django (pseudo). I am using Django 1.7 with Postgres 9.4.

Model BuySaleTransactionBreakDown with below fields:

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
closing_balance = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True)
date_created = models.BigIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
last_updated = models.BigIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
```

Model BuySaleTransaction with below fields:

```
infrastructure_unit = models.ForeignKey(InfrastructureUnit)
breakdown = models.ManyToManyField(BuySaleTransactionBreakDown)
date_created = models.BigIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
last_updated = models.BigIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
```

I want to get all the **latest** BuySaleTransactionBreakDown entries for all products for specific **infrastructure_unit**

I have written the below code

> BuySaleTransactionBreakDown.objects.annotate(Max('last_updated')).filter(buysaletransaction__infrastructure_unit = self)

But I am not getting the desired result, the group by clause is not working as expected.

Can you please help me with the right query. Thanks.

Comment: Is it essential to do this in one query? You could add a method to BuySaleTransaction that gets its latest BuySaleTransactionBreakDown. Do one query to find all the relevant BuySaleTransactions and use the method on each returned item to find their BreakDowns. It means more queries, but maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: The purpose of the query is to get the closing_balance for each product by going through the all transactions (BuySaleTransactionBreakDown) for a specific infrastructure_unit. Doing all these in one query makes this a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of `annotate` and `filter`.

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) says:

> When an annotate() clause is applied to a query, the annotation is computed over the state of the query up to the point where the annotation is requested. The practical implication of this is that filter() and annotate() are not commutative operations – that is, there is a difference between the query:

Comment: Doesn't help, same output

Answer (score 0):

According to django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by):

```
BuySaleTransactionBreakDown.objects.filter(buysaletransaction__infrastructure_unit = self).values('product').annotate(latest_entry=Max('last_updated'))order_by('-latest_entry') #assuming self is an infrastructure_unit object
```

Comment: This does not generate the desired output, because I need the latest BuySaleTransactionBreakDown entries group by product, meaning one (latest) transaction from each product group.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Postgres expects all parameters in the select statement to be present in the Group By clause.

So I have solved the problem by using the below code:

```
BuySaleTransactionBreakDown.objects.filter(buysaletransaction__infrastructure_unit = self).order_by('product__id','-last_updated').distinct('product__id')
```